# In android opengl method is there possible to declare loops or thread in onDrawFrame function

Tags: android, multithreading, opengl-es, android-animation

I made this code for rotating a single square in both clock and anticlock wise actually this is the example code for rotating in jayway tutorial.the code is not working.thanks in advance.:) sorry for english too..:)

```
public void onDrawFrame(final GL10 gl) {

Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try{

                gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
                gl.glLoadIdentity();
                gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 4.9f,-9.3f);
                //gl.glTranslatef(2.0f, 0.0f,0.0f);
                gl.glPushMatrix();
                gl.glRotatef(-angle, 0, 0, 1);  

                gl.glScalef(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
                square.draw(gl);
                gl.glPopMatrix();
                angle++;
                  Thread.sleep(5000);

            }
            catch(InterruptedException e){
            } 
           // To do
            gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            gl.glLoadIdentity();
            gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 4.9f,-9.3f);
            //gl.glTranslatef(2.0f, 0.0f,0.0f);
            gl.glPushMatrix();
            gl.glRotatef(angle, 0, 0, 1);   

            //gl.glScalef(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
            square.draw(gl);    
            gl.glPopMatrix();
            angle++;
}   
});t.start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenGL functions must be called from GLThread. That mean your opengl function must be called by 3 methods:

```
> onDrawFrame
> onSurfaceChanged 
> onSurfaceCreated
```

## About your example

> You can update the angle and draw the squares directly **without creating new thread** because onDrawFrame will be called repeat by GLThread.

```
public void onDrawFrame(final GL10 gl) {
    glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    mAngle++; // update angle

    // draw with clockwise rotation
    glPushMatrix();
    {
        glTranslatef(100, 100, 0);
        glRotatef(+mAngle, 0, 0, 1);
        drawSquare();
    }
    glPopMatrix();

    // draw with anti clockwise rotation
    glPushMatrix();
    {
        glTranslatef(100, 200, 0);
        glRotatef(-mAngle, 0, 0, 1);
        drawSquare();
    }
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

> **if you still want to create a new thread for updating, see the following example:**

```
float mAngle = 0;
boolean mExit = false;

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    Thread updateThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!mExit) {
                mAngle++;
                SystemClock.sleep(20);
            }
        }
    });
    updateThread.start();
}


public void onDrawFrame(final GL10 gl) {
    glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // clockwise rotation
    glPushMatrix();
    {
        glTranslatef(100, 100, 0);
        glRotatef(mAngle, 0, 0, 1);
        drawSquare();
    }
    glPopMatrix();

    // anti clockwise rotation
    glPushMatrix();
    {
        glTranslatef(100, 200, 0);
        glRotatef(-mAngle, 0, 0, 1);
        drawSquare();
    }
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Comment: not working refer this link too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15216983/in-android-to-rotate-a-square-in-clockwise-and-anticlockwise.